# Error in fullcalendar/resourcetimegrid plugin

Tags: angular

While i import resourceTimeGridPlugin and use it in calendar plugin of my application, it is showing compile errors

I tried to change my typescript versions and calendar versions but nothing helped

```
 this.calendarOptions = {
        plugins:[ resourceTimeGridPlugin, dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, listPlugin ],
        resources:[{id:1,title:'Doctor',color:'blue'},{id:2,title:'Actor',color:'red'},{id:3,title:'Dancer',color:'red'}],
        editable: true,
        // defaultView: 'timeGridWeek',
        slotDuration:duration,
        eventLimit: false,
        selectable: true,
        header: {
          left: 'prev,next today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'resourceTimeGridDay dayGridMonth timeGridWeek timeGridDay listWeek'
        },
        events: data
      };
```

> ERROR in node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(7,14): error TS2484: Export declaration conflicts with exported declaration of 'OptionsInput'.node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(8,26): error TS2484: Export declaration conflicts with exported declaration of 'EventDef'.
>   node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(34,14): error TS2484: Export declaration conflicts with exported declaration of 'Calendar'.
>   node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(41,24): error TS2484: Export declaration conflicts with exported declaration of 'DateSpanApi'.
>   node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(41,37): error TS2484: Export declaration conflicts with exported declaration of 'DatePointApi'.
>   node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(61,35): error TS2484: Export declaration conflicts with exported declaration of 'CalendarState'.
>   node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(70,14): error TS2484: Export declaration conflicts with exported declaration of 'EventMutation'.
>   node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(72,14): error TS2484: Export declaration conflicts with exported declaration of 'EventApi'.
>   node_modules/@fullcalendar/resource-common/main.d.ts(194,9): error TS2416: Property 'getKeysForEventDef' in type 'VResourceSplitter' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Splitter'.
>     Type '(eventDef: import("@fullcalendar/core").EventDef) => string[]' is not assignable to type '(eventDef: import("@fullcalendar/core/structs/event").EventDef) => string[]'.
>       Types of parameters 'eventDef' and 'eventDef' are incompatible.
>         Type 'import("@fullcalendar/core/structs/event").EventDef' is not assignable to type 'import("@fullcalendar/core").EventDef'.
>   node_modules/@fullcalendar/resource-common/main.d.ts(372,9): error TS2416: Property 'getKeysForEventDef' in type 'ResourceSplitter' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Splitter'.
>     Type '(eventDef: import("@fullcalendar/core").EventDef) => string[]' is not assignable to type '(eventDef: import("@fullcalendar/core/structs/event").EventDef) => string[]'.
>       Types of parameters 'eventDef' and 'eventDef' are incompatible.
>         Type 'import("@fullcalendar/core/structs/event").EventDef' is not assignable to type 'import("@fullcalendar/core").EventDef'.
>   node_modules/@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.d.ts(217,9): error TS2416: Property 'getKeysForEventDef' in type 'AllDaySplitter' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Splitter'.
>     Type '(eventDef: import("@fullcalendar/core").EventDef) => string[]' is not assignable to type '(eventDef: import("@fullcalendar/core/structs/event").EventDef) => string[]'.
>       Types of parameters 'eventDef' and 'eventDef' are incompatible.
>         Type 'import("@fullcalendar/core/structs/event").EventDef' is not assignable to type 'import("@fullcalendar/core").EventDef'.
>           Property 'resourceIds' is missing in type 'EventDef'.